Converting an old remote controlled fan to a Pull-chain fan
I have a Southwind II 52" fan at a new condo, which I believe comes with a receiver and a remote, but both of them are missing. (maybe the previous owners lost it).
As of right now, I just have a wall switch which turns the Light and the Fan ON. Can I somehow convert it to a 'pull chain' controlled fan?
I opened up the base cap and saw that the capacitor (CBB61) has two wires coming from it (a red and a white). In my mind, it seems as though I can just replace the old capacitor with a 'Capacitor+Pull-chain combo' (example attached: this capacitor would have 2 greys and 3 fan control wires coming out of it) and everything should be okay? Can this be done? Is there something else I need to be careful about?
EDIT: In the wiring image, I accidentally wrote 'Receiver'. I meant to write Capacitor.




Make sure local regulations allow you to do electrical in a multi-family building.  Quite a few require licensed electricians to do work like this.  This includes most of North America.

Universal remotes are available.  How do you know the receiver is missing?  did you take down the canopy to see?   Pull chains are 20th century, that is why many new fans do not come with them.

@RMDman   Pull chains do not need batteries and give you some exercise and much harder to lose.

@crip659, Pull chains don't make it easy to turn the fan up when you're in bed and your wife is having a hot-flash.

Add pull chains? I have no idea if that is possible or practical. But...
Everybody loses remotes. Nobody "loses" the receiver, because the receiver is mounted with the fan, often on top of the fan, and hardwired to it.
You really can't tell much from the inside wiring of the fan. What you need to do is take the fan down from the ceiling to find out:

Is there a receiver mounted on top of the fan?
How many wires are coming from ceiling? Not counting ground (green or bare) it could be two (usually black and white) or three (usually black, red and white)
How many wires are coming from the top of the fan? Not counting ground (green or bare) it could be two (usually black and white) or three (usually black, red or blue and white)

If you have a receiver, get a matching remote. The previous owners either lost the remote or took it with them without realizing it. (Or if they were nasty people, took with them on purpose. But I'd like to think that's not what happened.)
If there is no receiver and there are three wires coming from the ceiling and three wires going into the fan then you may be able to wire up separate switches for fan and light. Check wires going to the existing switch. If you have two wires from the fan going to one screw on the switch (which isn't the right way to do it, but is sometimes done anyway) or you have one wire from the ceiling going to two wires on the fan and the other wire is not white (because if it is white then it is neutral and can't be used as another switched hot) and is capped off on both ends (ceiling and switch) then it is a simple job to rewire for two switches - one for the fan and the other for the light.
If there are only two wires or in certain cases with three wires (switch loop with neutral) then there is no practical way to install a second switch without running new wires/cable between the switch box and the ceiling.
